# Pacote Nuget ASP

Tags: asp, nuget

Eu dou manutenção em um sistema ASP (legado é legado) que tenho dificuldade em controlar versões e atualizações do sistema.

Pensando sobre como melhorar isso e ganhar estabilidade para o sistema entre versões notei que o Nuget pode ser uma boa opção para esse fim.

**Mas como nem tudo é flor gostaria de ter algumas ideias quais limitações ou contras eu poderia encontrar em usar algo nesse sentido.**

Acredito que com isso seria possível até mesmo me arriscar com integração contínua no ASP.

Comment: Git acredito ser melhor já o Nuget seria pacotes... Se for versionamento Git.

Comment: Aqui usamos o GIT pra versionar o código.

O uso do Nuget seria por conta de criar dependências e controlar ela de forma mais fácil.

Pois o sistema é dividido em vários módulos alguns depende de outro outros dependem do core.

Ajudaria especialmente nesse ponto.

Comment: Entendi. Por exemplo o Laravel Framework tem vários pacotes todos eles separados quando um precisa do outro o pacote tem essa determinada referencia e insta as dependências. Como é asp tradicional (vbscript) é bem parecido com o jeito que o PHP utiliza por ser arquivos. O nuget talvez daria mas também daria muito trabalho. Bom é mais um alerta.